# What's the probability for picking up 3 points on a line of length 20 so that they create a rectangle of area <= 21?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

That's what I've come up so far but I don't know if this is right:

If you got a straight line of length 20, the only way to create a rectangle out of that is that a point must be at x=10 (let's call it y). Why? Because if I take a point at x<10 then the next line (on the right side, e.g. ---x------- for x=3) must be 10-x of length (and thus the next point must always be at x=10). The third point must be at 20-(10-x) (e.g. ---x-------y---z-------)

We now have to calculate the Omega, which is simply the integral of 10-x from 0 to 10. We get 50

But: A rectangle of area <= 21 is only possible for 0 < x <= 3, so if we integrate 10-x from 0 to 3 we get 25.5 as far as I've calculated it properly, which gives us a probability of more or less 50%

I don't consider the cases for the first point "x" being at >=10 because the "first choice of points" is not taken into account (theoretically I could've taken z as the first point and find x and y).

What are your thoughts on this?

EDIT: It's given that those points will always create a rectangle

Comment: Ah yes and you also have to take the integral of 10-x for 7 to 10 because for 7 <= x < 10 it's also possible to create a rectangle, the integral is 4.5 and in the end we get 30, which means that 30/50 = 60%

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you requiring that the sides have integer length?  Even so...why does there have to be a point at $x=10$?  Why not choose points at $x=1, x=2, x=11$?  Just to choose one example.  Those segments give you a rectangle with sides $1, 9$ for an area of $9$.

Comment: They do not have an integer length. There has to be a point at x=10 because you can't create a rectangle if there's no point at x=10. It may be a some sort of figure with 4 corners but definitely not a rectangle with four 90 degrees corners

Comment: First of all, if they don't have to integer length then there are infinitely many possibilities.  Secondly, I gave you an example which has no point at $x=10$.  Specifically, I take the segments $[0,1], [1,2], [2,11], [11,20]$ to form the sides of my rectangle.

Comment: No, you have to bend at those points x, y, z at 90 degrees. It's like taking a wire and making a rectangle out of this

Comment: This is not clear at all.  Now you have edited the problem so that you appear to speaking about probability.  But of course the probability that three points chosen uniformly at random define a rectangle is $0$.  Please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: I think I've made it clear right now, the points chosen will always create a rectangle. Sorry that I've edited the title, what I meant was the probability originally

Comment: This problem is a mess.  I think all you are saying is this: "choose a point uniformly on $[0,10]$.  What is the probability that the rectangle with sides $x$ and $10-x$ has area $≤21$?"  Is that it?

Comment: If so, the answer is clearly $.6$ since you require $x\in [0,3]$ or $x\in [7,10]$.